# Express - `req.body` is always empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to build a full stack(MERN) application. When I'm sending a request to my Express server with a JSON, I always see my req.body is empty. I can nowhere see my JSON inside my request.

I have tried using only `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`,but no change.

index.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for encoded bodies
console.log("App");
require("./schema/data");
require("./routes/home_routes")(app);
require("./routes/table_routes")(app);
require("./routes/utility_routes")(app);
```

utility_routes.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Data = mongoose.model("data");
module.exports = app => {
  app.get("/api/search_member", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Utility", req);
    console.log("Req Done");
    // const search = await Data.findById({ member_id: req.body.member_id });
    // console.log(search);
  });
};
```

request.body

```
[0]   body: {},
[0]   route:
[0]    Route {
[0]      path: '/api/search_member',
[0]      stack: [ [Layer] ],
[0]      methods: { get: true } } }
```

request from client

```
 onSearch = async value => {
      console.log(value);
      if (value) {
        const searchData = await axios.get("/api/search_member", { value });
        console.log(searchData);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Did you tried from postman or any other rest client?

Comment: @KrishnadasPC Yes. In postman, I can see the object only if I set Content-type as Application/JSON

Comment: You're using express, so: read through https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#express-route-specific and follow those code conventions (notably: you don't seem to be using the middleware functions at all, so there's no reason to expect it to work - go back to the docs and follow their example)

Comment: GET request isn't supposed to send Body to Server, use POST instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You are making a GET request. GET request do not send body. To get req.body, make POST request to server.

Firstly:-

    const searchData = await axios.post("/api/search_member", { value });

And Secondly,

     app.POST("/api/search_member", async (req, res) => {
        console.log("Utility", req);
        console.log("Req Done");            
      });
```

Comment: _"You are making a GET request. GET request do not send body."_ That's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to accept the `json`

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();   
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
 })); 

 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(cookieParser());
```

And in the request set headers like this.

```
Content-Type : application/json
```

Both the axios and http libraries from angular works with this settings for me.